# django rest framework, not serializable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new at using the django REST framework and I am having trouble to import a list of the members of a team

my query is

```
team_name_list = Project.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
```

which give an output :

```
<QuerySet [<MyUser: johndoe@gmail.com>, <MyUser: johndoe2@gmail.com>, <MyUser: johndoe3@gmail.com>, <MyUser: johndoe4@gmail.com>]>
```

The thing is when I try to import it in my context I get an error

```
Object of type 'MyUser' is not JSON serializable
```

I guess because the output of my query should be something ["johndoe@gmail.com","johndoe2@gmail.com","johndoe3@gmail.com","johndoe4@gmail.com"]

How can I make it work

Edited work: using serializer

I created serializer.py file that I imported in my views so now I do not get the error "not serializable" but my data does not showed up in my endpoint or in my inspect/console

i am I missing something ?

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

from registration.models import MyUser
from website.models import Team,Project

class MyUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = [
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        ]
```

Views:

from website.serializers import MyUserSerializer

I have a view that is linked my employe_detail_page.html

```
class EmployeeDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'Employee_Details.html'


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=self.kwargs['pk2'], members__project=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employee_name = MyUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        team_list = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
        team_list_pop = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all().exclude(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        context={
            'employee_name' : employee_name,
            'team_list' : team_list,
            'team_list_pop' : team_list_pop
        }
        return context
```

and in the template I include a dashboard.html using chartJS and this view

```
class EmployeeChartData(APIView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):

        project_name = Project.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk1']).name
        team_name_list = Project.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
        team_name_data = serializer(team_name_list)
        team_member_count = Project.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.count()
        main_items2 = [1,2,3,-4,5,6,-7,8,9,-10,-11,12,13,14,15,16]
        info_process_data = [4,6,2,8,4]
        info_process_data2 = [8,2,5,2,4]
        action_process_data = [5,3,9]
        motivation_data = [4,5,1,8]
        behaviour_data = [6,3,9,1]

        data = {
            #labels

            "labels_main_graph":labels_main_graph,
            "information_processing_label": information_processing_label,
            "action_process_label": action_process_label,
            "motivation_label": motivation_label,
            "behaviour_label":behaviour_label,
            #data

            "main2": main_items2,
            "info_process_data": info_process_data,
            "info_process_data2": info_process_data2,
            "action_process_data": action_process_data,
            "motivation_data":motivation_data,
            "behaviour_data":behaviour_data,
            #other
            "project_name":project_name,
            "team_member_count":team_member_count,
            "team_name_list":team_name_data

        }
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: `json.dumps({"emails": [i.email for i in team_name_list]})`

Comment: You have to serialize your query result to get json. Go through DRF Serialization [here] (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)

Comment: @ParulDixit, Hi thx for your answer, I read the docu .. I got rid of the error but still can't see my data .. I edited my post with my code if you can have a look please ;)

Comment: @Ben2pop can you share your view code.Just to know how you rendered the data.

Comment: sure, I have done it thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before returning response serialize your team_name_list

```
    team_name_list = Project.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
    serializer = self.get_serializer_class()
    team_name_data = serializer(team_name_list)
```

then in data dict:

```
    "team_name_list":team_name_data
```

Comment: I ma getting 'EmployeeChartData' object has no attribute 'get_serializer_class'

Comment: get_serializer_class is a method to get the respective serialize. However u can direct use the name of the serializer as you have define.

Comment: Could you be more clear I am not sure how to use the get_serializer_class please

Comment: In fact I am alway getting the error : Object of type 'ListSerializer' is not JSON serializable

Comment: @B I have added

Comment: @Ben2pop remove `many=True` to serialize single obj. i have edited my ans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160523/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-parul-dixit).